# What is "Task scanning" in NetBeans and how to turn it off?

Tags: netbeans

Sometimes when opening projects, NetBeans will display a "Task scanning" progress bar on the status bar. What exactly is it scanning for? Is it possible to turn it off as I noticed that sometimes it takes a while and maybe it's just my installation but sometimes I have to force it to stop when closing NetBeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a "Task List" plugin working. It does this:

> Provides the Task List window, which lists places of interest in your project, such as lines that contain "TODO", "XXX", "PENDING", Java compilation errors, and so on. You can click an entry in the list to navigate to the corresponding place in your code.

You can remove it by going to "Tools > Plugins" menu, "Installed" tab, selecting "Task List" from the installed plugin list and clicking "Uninstall" button. (These instructions are for NetBeans 6.5, but should be somewhat alike for all the other versions).
But I would advise against removing it - I find it pretty useful. There are times when I forget about several TODO's, and Tasks window is a great way to look 'em up.
If you can't see that window, you can access it through "Window > Task" menu, or by pressing Ctrl+6 (again, these instructions are for NetBeans 6.5)

Comment: Task Lists don't seem to have their own plugin in Netbeans 6.9, at least there's no entry for it in Plugins.  Any ideas how to disable it now?  I'm using the PHP distribution.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan Day: sorry, but we've dropped NetBeans after 6.5 in favour of JDeveloper :)

Comment: Confirming; does not appear to be a plugin in 7.0.1 either.

Answer (score 1):

Using Neatbeans 7.2.1

You can go to Tools->Options->Miscellaneous then under the Files tab uncheck Enable auto-scanning of sources. Whenever you want to have Netbeans scan you project you can go to Source->Scan for External Changes.

Tools->options->C++, or whichever language you are working with, under the Other tab uncheck Reparse on File Change.  Whenever you want to reparse right click your project Code Assistance->Reparse Project.

Answer (score 0):

It is scanning for the `// TODO blarblar` and `// FIXME ....` alikes.

You can disable it by removing the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans 7.0.1 you can't disable the Task List definitively.

Instead you can limit/avoid scan :

- Right click in Tasks window
- Filter -> Edit
- Unselect all

You can also cancel the running "Task scanning" process :

- Right click on the progress bar
- Click Cancel process

Comment: Unselecting all did not stop HTML error checking for me in NetBeans 7.0.1. Also, I cannot stop some processes in the progress bar, especially "scanning". NetBeans [ScanOnDemand Plugin](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand) did not appear to be solving this task-scanning issue.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the hints I gave only works for Compilers Errors, Issues, Maven POM pb, and TODO (at least in my version). And yes some Task can't be cancel, like "scanning", I think Netbeans need this one to works properly. If you want less check for HTML, you can go in Options -> Editor -> Hints, then select HTML and remove the HTML validator.