# How to disable task scanning for PHP edition of Netbeans 6.9

Tags: netbeans, ide, tasklist

Task scanning on very large projects seems to bog down the IDE.  I love this editor and it's ability to parse large complex projects such as Magento, but performance can get iffy.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077974/task-scanning-in-netbeans/1078040#1078040), it used to be possible to disable the plugin, but it seems that version 6.9 of Netbeans has made that impossible.  Any ideas on how to disable?

Thanks,
JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netbeans 6.9 you can install the [ScanOnDemand](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ScanOnDemand) plugin. It allows you to start the scanning process manually instead of letting Netbeans decide when to scan.

Comment: Thanks!  The wiki describes it as `experimental`.  Should I be concerned about stability?

Comment: It work's for me. Haven't had any stability problems with it.